# LWJGL Collision detection 3D?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm new to lwjgl and openGL and i'm wanting to know how to do collision detection in 3D, I have a 3D sorta world setup but i don't know how to detect collisions.

Comment: OpenGL just draws thing and there's no such concept as a scene or models in OpenGL. There are just points, lines and triangles. So for anything that goes beyond that you either have to program it yourself, or you make use of some 3rd party libraries. For your purpose I suggest you look for some physics simulation library; even if you don't want physics, collision detection is an integral part of the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

LWJGL is just doing the graphics part. If you need a good collision detection or physics library for Java then [JBullet](http://jbullet.advel.cz/) is an option. JBullet is a Java port of the Bullet library used by many games.